# nginx php7 only working in document root

Tags: php, nginx, file-permissions, vps, php-7

beginner here ;)

I moved a page from one VPS to another and after installing nginx,php7 etc (using [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04)) everything is working great.
Added SSL no problem at all.

However if I execute any php files (f.e hello world)  in any newly created subfolder f.e mydomain.pw/newfolder/index.php I get a blank result.
If I execute the same file in the page root folder (WP), it works fine.

I have added my user to the www-data group and gave the same permission as I did on the former VPS.
If I check the nginx error log or php7.0-fpm.log I get no error at all.

If anyone has any hint or idea what the problem is, I'd really appreciate it. 
I suspect a permission error but searched on SO and Google without success.

Here is my nginx conf :

```
server {
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
  listen 80 default_server;
  # listen on the www and non-www host
  server_name www.mydomain.pw mydomain.pw;

  root /var/www/mydomain;
  index index.html index.htm index.php ;

  # and redirect to the https host (declared below)

  return 301 https://mydomain.pw$request_uri;

  location ~ \.php$ {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_index index.php;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
server {
  listen [::]:443 ssl;

  listen 443 ssl;

  server_name www.mydomain.pw mydomain.pw;

  root /var/www/mydomain;
  index index.html index.htm index.php;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.pw/fullchain.pem;

  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.pw/privkey.pem;

  location ~ \.php$ {

            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;

            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

            fastcgi_index index.php;

            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

            include fastcgi_params;

      }

  location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 365d;
  }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start by checking the server’s error logs ...

Comment: checkout you nginx access logs and error logs

Comment: `error_log $document_root/info_log.txt info;`